# Variation of nim game

Tags: game-theory

Two players take turns taking an integer from [2, 30]. When a player takes a number that has a common factor with a number previously taken, that players loses. Would you prefer to go first or second, and what is your optimal strategy?

My initial thought:
I first considered how many prime numbers there are within this interval (10). Once all the prime numbers have been said, any number taken after that will result in that players loss. So my strategy revolves around ensuring you are the player who gets to take away the last prime.
To me, this implies forcing the other player to take a prime number first, and then any time he takes a prime you take a prime as well to keep the number of primes even. But how can you force the other player to take the first prime?

Comment: As a huge hint, what numbers are left for the rest of the game if the first player takes 6?  what if the first player takes 30?

Comment: Oh wow, I see. That would leave only the prime numbers. So you would always be player 1 and open with 30. Thank you.

Comment: If you open with $30$ that leaves $7$ primes, so the other guy will get the last prime and you will lose. I would open with $6$.